# Switch between onItemClick and onItemLongClick event of Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I want to ask how to switch and select only one event under the listview. My code below is working. But when the OnItemLongClick fires, the OnItemClick also fires. How can I switch the event where only one event will be detected:

```
lstResult.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //showToast(arg0.getItemIdAtPosition(position) +  "");
                 String str = searchWhere(lstResult.getItemAtPosition(position) + "");
                 String word = lstResult.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                 showDialog(word,str);
            }

        });
        lstResult.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showToast(lstResult.getItemAtPosition(position) + "");
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Return boolean true at the end of OnItemLongClick.

Comment: from de documentation: "true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise"

Answer (score 8):

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) of OnItemLongClickListener:

> Returns
>   true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise

You should return `true` if long click is fired.

Answer (score 1):

When you return false on your OnItemLongClickListener so this wouldn't be fire ,so you can define a boolean variable to switch between your Listeners